# Display Php Code in HTML

Tags: php

Check the following code. I want to display the send mail parameters like mail, subject and message in HTML page. Please let me know how can i display it in HTML

```
// send email notification

if (($ed['notify_email'] == 'true') && ($ed['notify_email_address'] != ''))
{           
    $email = $ed['notify_email_address'];

    $template = event_notify_template('email',$ed,$ud,$od,$loc);

    sendEmail($email, $template['subject'], $template['message'], true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's echo or print methods to display variables.

```
<?php echo($myVariable); ?>
```

or

```
<?php print($myVariable); ?>
```

If you want to perform your sendmail action in one php page, then redirect to another and show the data, then you need some means of storing it between views.

1. if your sendmail is successful store a record of it in your database, and pass the key for that record to your next php page.  In that one, query the data for that key, get the result and display it using echo or print.
2. Similar to above, but store the data in the user's session (not really advised), and display it on the next page using echo or print.
3. Don't store the data, but pass it along to your next page as GET key/value pairs (not really recommended either), access it in the $_GET[] array and display it using echo or print.

The best solution in your situation is option 1. Store the record, look it up when you need it and display it.  It's more secure and you're not putting the user's data in session or passing along in the query string.  Plus it gives you a historical record in your database of actions in your site.

Comment: I don't know how your application is set up in regards to your 'order page' so I can't answer that or tell you where to put what code. But if you're trying to display a PHP variable, you would use echo or print with your variable.  If the code you posted above is in the actual view that the user sees then you can echo those variables out below the sendEmail method.  If your 'order page' is something that is redirected to after this sendmail function happens then you need to be able to pass those variables to that order page (typically through a controller) then echo them there.

Comment: **Robert This is the complete code i need to display it in other page**

from php to another php page

Comment: The brackets in the code above are not needed. `print $myVariable;`